# iterator on JSONArray in forEach?

Tags: java, json, foreach, iterator

I am trying to read and parse a JSON file. I successfully read it but I have compilation error at

```
emptList.forEach(emp -> parseEmpObj((JSONObject) emp));
```

In the YouTube video it works like that but not on my computer.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JSONParser jsonP = new JSONParser();
        
        try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\test.json"))
        {
            Object obj = jsonP.parse(reader);
            JSONArray emptList = new JSONArray();
            emptList.add(obj);
            System.out.println(emptList);

            emptList.forEach(emp -> parseEmpObj((JSONObject) emp));
            
            
            
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch(ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
        
        
    }
    
    private static void parseEmpObj(JSONObject emp)
    {
        JSONObject emptObj = (JSONObject) emp.get("glossary");
        String title = (String) emptObj.get("title");
        
        System.out.print(title);
    }
```

The error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    emp cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error on token "-", -- expected
    emp cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: @Wokers What Java version are you using?

Comment: I use json-simple-1.1.1 and my java version is 1.8.0_231 @Ivar

Comment: @Wokers this works just fine when I paste it into my IDE...

Comment: Works for me as well. The syntax gives me the impression that it doesn't recognize the lambda function. Those are new in Java 8. Are you sure that you are running this code on that version when you get this error?

Comment: Yes, when i check again, i see jdk1.8.0_152(default). Even I dont have any other installed JREs. @Ivar

Comment: @Wokers It works fine for me using Java 1.8.0_251. Can't help you much further I'm afraid.

Comment: Did you specify the java target version somewhere? Even with JDK 1.8, you could still compile for Java 7.